# Terraform Google Cloud: Executing a Remote Script on a VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, remote-execution

I'm trying to execute a Script on a Google VM through Terraform.

First I tried it via Google Startup Scripts. But since the metadata is visible in the Google Console (startup scripts count as metadata) and that would mean that anybody with read access can see that script which is not acceptable.

So i tried to get the script from a Storage Account. But for that i need to attach a service account to the VM so the VM has the rights to access the Storage Account. Now people that have access to the VM also have access to my script as long as the service account is attached to the VM. In order to "detach" the service account i would have to stop the VM. Also if i don't want to permanently keep the attachment of the service account i would have to attach the service account via a script which requires another stop and start of the VM. This is probably not possible and also really ugly.

I don't understand how the remote-exec ressource works on GCP VMs. Because i have to specify a user and a userpassword to connect to the VM and then execute the script. But the windows password needs to be set manually via the google console, so i can't specify those things at this point in time.

So does anybody know how I can execute a Script where not anybody has access to my script via Terraform?

Greetings :) and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just running a gcloud script in which i removed the Metadata from the VM after the Terraform apply was finished. In my Gitlab pipeline i just called the script in the "after_script"-section. Unfortunately the credentials are visible for approximately 3min.